How to limit CMake components' propagated dependencies
I would like to optimize my CMake project, which uses Conan as dependency management tool. It is an executable, which depends on few Conan libraries. However, the need for sharing some headers and some dependencies arose, so I've split the project, resulting in two new targets additional to the already existing executable target.
I want to link those targets/components to various other projects, depending on the needs. They both share distinct headers and links. The thing is, I can't force CMake or Conan to respect this distinction and I've started to doubt if that's even possible.
To be more precise: I mean that, by linking myproject::myLib in another project, I don't want to include other libs, which would be, let's say, Boost, OpenSSL and MyOtherLib, which are linked to myproject::iface with INTERFACE scope and indirectly to myExecutable (thanks to linking iface component). Is this possible?
I'm using GCC 14.2, CMake 3.26 and Conan 1.65.0.
CMakeLists.txt:
project(myProject)

// ...

// looking for dependencies installed by Conan
find_package(Boost CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(MyOtherLib CONFIG REQUIRED)

// main executable target
add_executable(myExecutable
  one.cpp
  two.cpp
)

// new static library target
add_library(myLib STATIC)
target_sources(myLib
  PRIVATE
    lib/myLib/threeLib.cpp
  PUBLIC
    FILE_SET libHeaders
    TYPE HEADERS
    BASE_DIRS lib/myLib/include
    FILES
      lib/myLib/threeLib.h
target_link_libraries(myLib PRIVATE boost::boost)

// new header only component target
add_library(iface INTERFACE)
target_sources(iface
  INTERFACE
    FILE_SET ifaceHeaders
    TYPE HEADERS
    BASE_DIRS include
    FILES
      include/fourHeader.h
      include/fiveHeader.h
target_link_libraries(iface
  INTERFACE
    boost::boost
    openssl::openssl
    myotherlib::myotherlib

// executable is using both of these libs/components
target_link_libraries(myExecutable 
  PRIVATE 
    iface
    myLib
)
// ...

conanfile.py
# some imports
class myProject(ConanFile):
    # some attributes and settings
    # version numbers might be randomized
    generators = "CMakeDeps", "CMakeToolchain"
    requires = "boost/1.80.0", "openssl/3.3.5", "myotherlib/1.0@myremote/testing"
    
    def layout(self):
        cmake_layout(self)

    def generate(self):
        toolchain = CMakeToolchain(self)
        toolchain.generate()
        deps = CMakeDeps(self)
        deps.generate()

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()

I've tried many things. At the beginning, I had problems with including headers of both components but I've managed to fix it with CMake's install:
install(
  TARGETS iface
  EXPORT ifaceTargets
  FILE_SET ifaceHeaders
  DESTINATION include)

install(
  EXPORT ifaceTargets
  FILE ifaceTargets.cmake
  NAMESPACE myproject::
  DESTINATION lib/cmake/iface)

install(
  TARGETS myLib
  EXPORT myLibTargets
  FILE_SET myLibHeaders
  DESTINATION myLib_include
  ARCHIVE_DESTINATION lib)

install(
  EXPORT myLibTargets
  FILE myLibTargets.cmake
  NAMESPACE myproject::
  lib/cmake/mylib)

However, the problem was still the fact that linking myproject::myLib effects with linking all other libraries.
I've tried to add the component info in cpp_info section of the Conan file, hoping that, in setting the requires field, I would be able to 'override' some default generated dependencies:
def package(self):
    cmake = CMake(self)
    cmake.install()

def package_info(self):
    self.cpp_info.components["myLib"].libs = ["myLib"]
    self.cpp_info.components["myLib"].set_property("cmake_target_name", "myproject::myLib")
    self.cpp_info.components["myLib"].includedirs = ["myLib_include"]
    self.cpp_info.components["myLib"].requires = []

    self.cpp_info.components["iface"].set_property("cmake_target_name", "myproject::iface")
    self.cpp_info.components["iface"].includedirs = ["include"]
    self.cpp_info.components["iface"].requires = ["boost::boost", "openssl::openssl", "myotherlib::myotherlib"]    

No effect though. Linking myproject::myLib is still linking Boost and other libraries, which I would like to avoid without atomizing the project.
Any ideas how could I achieve this division of propagated links, when all targets/components are defined in one CMake project and one Conan file? Is that even possible without separating targets to distinct project with their own CMakeLists and Conan files?

This should be the expected behavior in Conan 2. If some of the consumers of your project links with one of the components, it shouldn't bring all dependencies, just the .requires ones. If this is not the case, the best would be to report it as a bug in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues.

@drodri This is conan 1, so it could be behaviour that's been fixed in conan 2. Upgrading would be ideal especially considering stuff will keep breaking more and more, but it's not always a realistic option if trapped by other legacy systems. Still, checking if the same problem remains with conan 2 and this example code would be useful info.

After some research and conversation under conan's github thread I've came up to the conclusion that it's not a Conan's or CMake's thing, but just the way static/interface libraries are linked.
My iface and myLib libraries where "linked" against other static libraries, but there isn't something like linking a static library against other static library. There is still a lot of things in this matter I need to aknowledge, but as far as I understand they are all linked against the first shared library or executable in the hierarchical tree. Compiling a static library does not call the linking phase, so target_link_libraries against such would cause only including public headers.
It looks like there is no way to treat CMake/Conan components of one project as completely distinct in the means of static dependencies. Every requirement from the Conan dependencies' recipe will take part somewhere in the linking phase.
I would be grateful if someone confirmed this. Otherwise, if put me right, I would check theirs answer.
